# What are these razor blades called and where can I buy them?

Tags: hand-tools

[image: 5 hole double sided razor blade]
[image: In the knife]

I have this razor blade knife that I cannot find replacement blades for. I love the knife but I don't even know what to search for.

What are these blades called and where can I get them?

The metal handle has martor-handy Inox no. 444 Solingen Germany on it.

Comment: Have you gone to the utility knife section of the hardware store and looked ?

Comment: Shopping questions are off topic, are there any markings on the holder? Like a brand name. I have not seen that style knife.

Comment: Looks a lot like a standard "old style" razor blade (for shaving) would fit, but the present blade is a bit different from that.

Comment: @AlaskaMan that's the first thing I've tried. Also "5 hole razor blade" on Google. I didn't think to look for a name on the tool itself, will update with that info

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Ed Beal, I looked at the name on the tool. That also led me to take a scouring pad to the blade itself and lo and behold it's a Cartonax 45
[image: Cartonax 45 blade]

Answer (score 0):

That looks vaguely like a regular safety razor blade. I'm a bit dubious as to the dimensions, though. I measured mine at 1 12/16" x 14/16", with holes 5/16" from each end. If those (approximately) match your blade, and both sides are sharp, it's probably it.

The main reason I doubt this is that most safety razors are a bit shorter on the blade ends than the middle, while utility razors aren't.

Answer (score 0):

looks like this one.

[https://www.amazon.com/Metal-Safety-Cutter-replacement-blades/dp/B01EPE7LJO/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01EPE7LJO)

I searched "box cutter"